# How can we show app icon image on progress dialog box in android studio?

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-studio-2.1

Can I add my app icon image on `ProgressbarDialog` box in android?

Following is my code:

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
progressDialog.setMessage("...");
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add an icon to your `ProgressDialog` add `setIndeterminateDrawable(Drawable icon)` to the variable to `ProgressDialog`:

[image: Example Icon]

```
progressDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(Drawable_Icon_From_Drawable);
```

Here,  `setIcon()` will give you a title icon:

[image: b]

```
progressDialog.setIcon(your_icon);
```

Comment: Can you used an animated GIF when calling SetIndeterminateDrawable()?

Answer (score 0):

```
progressDialog.setIcon();
```

Use this to set app icon on progress dialog. Pass your app icon in above method.

Answer (score 0):

You can set app icon using `setIcon()` method before `show()`.

```
progressDialog.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
```